# C expressions and their execution

Tags: c, expression

I have a question about the C expression `*cmd++='\0'`.

The program is as below:

```
void parse(char *cmd, char **arg)
{
    while(*cmd!='\0')
    {
        while(*cmd==' ' || *cmd=='\t'||*cmd=='\n')
            *cmd++='\0';
            *arg++=cmd;
        while(*cmd!='\0'&& *cmd!=' ' && *cmd!='\t' && *cmd!='\n')
        cmd++;
    }

    *arg='\0';
}
```

Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Have you traced it with debugger?

Comment: It's not `cmd++='\0'`, it's `*cmd++='\0'`.

Comment: ok if it is *cmd++='\0' what it will do? please expand the expression.

Answer (score 2):

It assigns a value to what the pointer points to and increases the pointer after.

```
*cmd++='\0';
```

can be translated to:

```
*cmd='\0'  // null char
cmd+=1
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `*cmd='\0'` at the first line?

Comment: Yes, I got a little confused o.O Thanks

Comment: No, is pointer arithmetic and lvalue assignment but mixed up to be cool and confuse others ;)

Comment: Note that `*++cmd='\0'` is also possible. In this case the next value in memory is assigned instead of current one.

Comment: Yes, that's actually how I interpreted first

Answer (score 2):

Following the operator precedence
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

the line

```
 *cmd++='\0';
```

is equivalent to:

```
*cmd = '\0';
cmd++;
```

because cmd++ will return the original value and then increment, if you want to increment first, should be ++cmd